# When to extend a class vs interfacing in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, dependency-injection, extend

Say I'm creating a chest with a lock...

**Extending**

```
  class Lock
  {
    public $locked = false;
    function lock()
    {
      $this->lock = true;
    }
    function unlock()
    {
      $this->lock = false;
    }
  }

  class Chest extends Lock
  {
  }

  $myChest = new Chest;
```

**Using Interfaces:**

```
<?php
  interface Lock
  {
    protected $locked;
    function lock();
    function unlock();
  }
  trait LockTrait
  {
    protected $locked = false;
    function lock()
    {
      $this->lock = true;
    }
    function unlock()
    {
      $this->lock = false;
    }
  }
  class Chest implements Lock
  {
    use LockTraits;
  }
  $myChest = new Chest;
```

**Using Class-Based Dependency Injection:**

```
  class Lock
  {
    public $locked = false;
    function lock()
    {
      $this->lock = true;
    }
    function unlock()
    {
      $this->lock = false;
    }
  }

  class Chest
  {
    protected $lock;
    function __construct($lock)
    {
      $this->lock = $lock;
    }
  }

  $myChest = new Chest(new Lock);
```

There are differences in both implementation, and characteristics of the resulting object. Extending and using interfaces will result in `Chest` objects which have the properties and methods of the `Lock` class. Injecting a new instance of the `Lock` class into the constructor of the `Chest` class will result in a property of the `Chest` class being a lock.

It seems to me that the best way to create my `Chest` object is to inject a `Lock` instance into the `Chest` constructor. This leads me to a second question though. Where would I use interfaces and extensions?

The answer to that question seems to be, "When I have multiple classes that share similar characteristics!" I would then is the "is a" principle to abstract traits.

However, when should I extend, and when should I use interfaces? I can use many interfaces while I can only `extend` one class. Why ever extend? Why not just use interfaces?

Comment: If you don't need to inject the lock, you can just create one in the chest constructor. I use extends when I want to add functionality to an existing class. I use interfaces when I want to interact in the same way with objects of different classes. I use dependency injection if the calling code needs to interact directly with a component of an object.

Comment: IMHO, following existing design pattern could solve this issue. This design pattern example may help a lot https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP